# Change the side of the same tcolorbox rule depending on the page side

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm trying to make [this box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122135/how-to-add-a-png-icon-on-the-right-side-of-a-tcolorbox-title) looking a bit better by placing the rule on the right on odd pages and on the left on even pages. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\newenvironment{boxWarning}[1]{%
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
    \def\myrule {rightrule}
    \def\posiz {east}
  \else
    \def\myrule {leftrule}
    \def\posiz {west}
  \fi
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,enhanced,arc=0mm,colback=gray!5,colframe=gray, \myrule=12mm,
    overlay={%
       \node[anchor=north \posiz,outer sep=2pt] at (frame.north \posiz) {%
           \includegraphics[width=8mm]{img/attenzione.png}%
       };%
    }]%
    #1%
  }%
{\end{tcolorbox}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{boxWarning}
\lipsum[2]
\end{boxWarning}
\newpage
\begin{boxWarning}
\lipsum
\end{boxWarning}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, a problem arises when the box is displayed on two pages: the side rule remains on the same side on both pages. Another "fine tuning" could be to not display again the icon on the second page.
[Here's the icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac0su.png)

Comment: With the current setting of `tcolorbox` you can't achieve this without a lot of internal changes. However you second question is answered in the documentation. A simple search of "overlay" helps.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The progress of science is unstoppable ... ;-) v2.33 has a `toggle left and right` option now :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Great. It would be nice if you can provide a public github repository ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've decided to answer questions now two day BEFORE they are asked ... ;-)
tcolorbox 2.33 (4/7/2013) has a left and right toggle feature which allows to switch the left and right rules on even pages. You can find this feature on page 22 of v2.33 :-)
Note the usage of the `changepage` package which gives the even/odd decision rule and the `\ifoddpage` macro used for the overlay.
For your example, you can use it like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{changepage}

\newtcolorbox{boxWarning}{enhanced,breakable,
  check odd page,toggle left and right,arc=0mm,
  colback=gray!5,colframe=gray,rightrule=12mm,
  overlay unbroken and first={%
    \ifoddpage\coordinate (X) at ([xshift=-6mm,yshift=-6mm]frame.north east);
         \else\coordinate (X) at ([xshift=6mm,yshift=-6mm]frame.north west);\fi
    \node at (X) {\includegraphics[width=8mm]{attenzione.png}};}
  }

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{boxWarning}
\lipsum[2]
\end{boxWarning}
\newpage
\begin{boxWarning}
\lipsum
\end{boxWarning}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! I was just thinking about a feature request... An update in zero time :)